# socket passing between processes

Tags: sockets, ipc, tcp, winsock

Is there a way to pass a socket between processes (not same address space) in Windows?

I find this info [Shared Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/shared-sockets-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN), therefore believe that it is possible.

"**The WSADuplicateSocket function is introduced to enable socket sharing across processes**"...

More info : at source code of Apache (httpd-2.2.11-win32-src.zip) have usage for api WSADuplicateSocket with comments.

[EDIT]
Recently I find this great sample about this question.
[How duplication is done in the unmanaged world - Socket Duplication - Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20150111081526/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/malarch/archive/2005/12/14/503884.aspx)
[Is it possible to transfer sockets from unmanaged processes? - Socket Duplication - Part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104003406/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/malarch/archive/2005/12/26/507461.aspx)

Comment: You can use a named pipe to redirect i/o from multiple client processes.  Not a shared socket but pretty simple.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

See the Remarks section of [WSADuplicateSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741565(VS.85).aspx). It effectively says you can use Your Favorite Interprocess Communication Scheme to send the WSAPROTOCOL_INFO structure (it's just data!) to the target.

There are lots of IPC schemes. I'd probably use shared memory with [Boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). But you could use SendMessage if the target has a window + message loop. Or the Clipboard API, for that matter (though somewhat weird). The mechanism is your choice.

Answer (score 3):

If you're creating the child process there are some things that might do it for you.  See

http://www.tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/passing-sockets.html 
(I know that this one worked in the ancient past; no idea if it works on current versions)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx

-- MarkusQ